# Does the Order of the Scribes ability Awakened Spellbook change the damage type of cantrips

Tags: dnd-5e, wizard, unearthed-arcana, archetype

On the newest [UA Subclass Revisited](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/UA2020_SubclassesRevisited_0512.pdf), the Wizard gains the ability to change the damage type of spells they cast for the damage type of other spells they have in their book.

Is this applicable to Cantrips?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### No

The ability says:

> When you **cast a wizard spell with a spell slot**, you can temporarily
>   replace its damage type with the damage type of another spell in your
>   spellbook, as your spellbook magically alters the spell’s formula for
>   this casting.

Since cantrips do not require a spell slot they are not affected by this ability

Comment: It may be worth noting that they can't even change the damage type of a 1st level or higher spell to a damage type of one of their cantrips. This is because cantrips are not in their spellbook. "Your spellbook is the repository of the wizard spells you know, except your cantrips, which are fixed in your mind."

Comment: does having Chromatic orb in your spellbook means that you add acid, cold, fire, lightning, poison, thunder damage types available?

Comment: That sounds like a separate question, though I personally would rule that it does, though I could see an argument made over the word choice of "*the* damage type"